# Angularjs - how to load images/videos after clicking on its title

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a directive which opens hidden details when user clicks the title, but I'm not sure what is the best strategy to load images using angular directive. I'd like to only load images(array) and videos if user clicks on its title. I don't want to preload images/videos.

I have created a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZdyP2/9/

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="movie in movies" data-movies></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    angular.module('App', []).
    // sample data     
    controller('MoviesCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.movies =[
            {
             'title': 'Despicable Me 2',
             'images':['http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/db/Despicable_Me_Poster.jpg',     'http://intl.despicableme.com/splashpage/images/centergraphic.jpg'],
             'video': 'XQG89cwhmJU'
             },
            {
             'title': ' Monsters University',
             'images': ['http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2a/Monsters_University_poster_3.jpg'],
             'video': 'ODePHkWSg-U'
             }        
           ]
    }).
    directive('movies', function(){
        return {
            template: '{{movie.title}}'+
                '<div class="movieInfo"><h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>' +
                '<img src="{{image}}" ng-repeat="image in movie.images"><br>' +
                '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{movie.video}}"></iframe></div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){ 
                elem.bind('click', function(){
                    // load image/video now
                    elem.find('.movieInfo').toggle();
                })
            }
        }  
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ng-if (available in AngularJS 1.1.5)
This directive will not render element at all, if condition is false.
http://jsfiddle.net/dUz5a/5/

```
directive('movies', function(){
    return {
        template: '<div ng-click="movie.show=!movie.show">{{movie.title}}</div>'+
        '<div ng-if="movie.show"><h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>' +
        '<img ng-src="{{image}}" ng-repeat="image in movie.images"><br>' +
            '<iframe ng-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{movie.video}}"></iframe></div>'
    }
})
```

Comment: This is great!!! Would you please show me how to do this without ng-if? I'm using angular v1.0.7 and can not upgrade for the time being.

Comment: As I understand it ng-if is actually just an ng-switch that only expects one condition. So ng-switch should work for you, its just an extra line or two of code.